# React Routes v4 behaving different depending on index

Tags: reactjs, react-router-v4

Here is the layout I wanted to create

```
Login => '/login'
Main  => '/'
      => Home => '/'
      => Pageone = '/pageone'
      => Pagetwo = '/pagetwo'
```

Here is the code i tried to do that

```
<BrowserRouter>  
  <Switch> 
      <Main> 
         <Route exact path='/' component={Home} /> 
         <Route path='/pageone' component={PageOne}/> 
         <Route path='/pagetwo' component={PageTwo}/>   
      </Main>
     <Route path="/login" component={Login}/>
  </Switch>  
</BrowserRouter>
```

While not using `Switch` nested routes worked perfectly but both the `Main` and `Login` rendered even while using `exact` . When using `Switch`, navigating to nested routes showed blank page but outer routes worked perfectly.

But simply changing the `<Route path="/login" component={Login}/>` to top made everythigg works perfectly

```
<BrowserRouter>  
  <Switch> 
     <Route path="/login" component={Login}/>
     <Main> 
         <Route exact path='/' component={Home} /> 
         <Route path='/pageone' component={PageOne}/> 
         <Route path='/pagetwo' component={PageTwo}/>   
      </Main>
  </Switch>  
</BrowserRouter>
```

Is this intended behavior or a bug ?

`Main` component content

```
<div>
   <NavBar ></NavBar>  
   {this.props.children} 
   <FooTer></FooTer>
</div>
```

here are my dependencies

```
"bootstrap": "^4.2.1",
"classnames": "^2.2.6",
"react": "^16.7.0",
"react-dom": "^16.7.0",
"react-materialize": "^2.6.0",
"react-router-dom": "^4.3.1",
"react-scripts": "2.1.3"
```

Answer (score 0):

The intended behavior for `Switch` is to only ever render one matched route. Put only mutually exclusive routes in it. Reading your question, I think the routes are not completely independent. E.g. maybe some of the content present in `/` route also needs to be displayed in other routes. To do this, you can try this -

```
<BrowserRouter>
  {/* Shared content in this route. This is always matched and rendered. */}
  <Route path="/" component={SharedChrome} />
  <Switch>
    <Route path="/" component={Home} />
    <Route path='/pageone' component={PageOne}/> 
    <Route path='/pagetwo' component={PageTwo}/>
    <Route path="/login" component={Login}/>
  </Switch>
</BrowserRouter>
```

And modify the content in components of routes inside the `Switch` to not have the shared content which will be rendered by `SharedChrome` component.